MySQL 8.4 LTS on ARM64 Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
I am wondering if it is already possible, or if it will soon be possible, to install the MySQL 8.4.x LTS community server onto an Ubuntu ARM64 24.04 LTS server without compiling from source?
I have installed the 24.04 LTS of Ubuntu onto an ARM64 device. If I try sudo apt install mysql-server I get 8.0.39 of MySQL server. There does not appear to be any other versions of the server available at the moment via the built-in apt sources.
I have tried to install the mysql-apt-config package from MySQL (at the time of writing, the version of that is mysql-apt-config_0.8.32-1_all.deb). The resulting auto-config script does support 8.4 LTS - but then when I run sudo apt update again, I get:

N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-apt-config/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-8.4-lts/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'


If MySQL 8.4.x is an absolute requirement, and if you are running an arm64v8 architecture, then Docker would be the fastest and most logical way to go to fulfill this need

you can try to download Linux generic ARM 64-bit from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
or wait a little (i can see mysql-server-8.4 in plucky proposed, very likely that is will be backported later).
